# Partial matching a string against a regex in swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I'm trying to create regexp with format "dd-dd-dd" in Swift

I came up with this :

```
(\d{1,2})(-)(\d{1,2})(-)(\d{1,2})
```

This pattern gives me correct result if the string is given as a whole. Example :

```
12-32-42 -> correct
2-32-1   -> correct
2--32-3  -> incorrect
```

I will be using this pattern in textfields. 
What I would like to know is if the typed string is heading towards positive regexp check. Example :

```
12     -> correct
-12-32 -> correct
12-    -> correct
-12--  -> incorrect
```

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Only one dash between number is correct.

Comment: Why is `-12-32` correct? It starts with `-`. I'd suggest `let pattern = "^\\d{1,2}(?:-(?:\\d{1,2}(?:-\\d{0,2})?)?)?$"`, see https://regex101.com/r/eHHG2l/1.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to list to possible combinations in an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
^(?:\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}-|-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}|\d{1,2})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lQyAJC/2)

Comment: Maybe not perfect, but it works and that's exactly what l wanted. Thank you!